# strange behavior of unsigned long long int in loop

Tags: c++, loops, c++11

While was solving [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sam-and-substrings/problem) problem on hackerrank, I noticed a strange thing in the for loop. First, let me show an example code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define modVal 1000000007;

int main() {
    for(long long int i=2;i>=0;--i){
        cout<<"here: "<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

> input: 123
>
> output: here: 2
>   here: 1
>   here: 0
>   164

Now, when I change `long long int` to `unsigned long long int` in for loop for the initialization of variable `i`. The variable `i` gets initialized with `18446744073709551615`. Why is this happening?

Comment: it doesn't get initialised with 18446744073709551615. it gets initialised to 2. And because it is unsigned, after two goes round the loop it gets set to a very large positive number. Being unsigned, it can't ever be negative.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: `#define modVal 1000000007;` Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the variable is unsigned, `i >= 0` is *always* true. So your loop never ends. When i gets to 0, the next -- makes `i` 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF (decimal 18446744073709551615).

Comment: To be fair, this is a common bug and, although once experienced you look out for it, in a sense it's quite subtle. After all, you told your loop not to go past 0! Sort of.

Comment: A good compiler however will warn on i >=0 (Condition is always true)

Comment: @hs use an IDE.

Comment: @hs if this answer solved your problem you might want to mark it as the correct answer. Then in a search people can see that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Because unsigned types can't be negative, attempting to set them to a negative value will make them wrap around and instead hold `std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - abs(value) + 1` where `T` is the type and `value` the value below `0`.

In your loop once `i` reaches `0` the condition `i >= 0` is still met and thus it would get decremented to `-1` but that is impossible for unsigned types as explained above and thus the loop will never exit.

Answer (score 3):

The unsigned numbers as the name suggests don't take signed values. So when i = -1 it is actually  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF(18446744073709551615 in decimal).

You can see that yourself with the modified program.

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 #define modVal 1000000007;

 int main() {
    for(unsigned long long int i=2;i>=0;--i){
         cout<<"here: "<<i<<endl;
       if(i > 3)
          return 0;
   }
 }
```